# Welch T-test between two populations of points with uncertainties

Tags: t-test, uncertainty

I have two populations of points and I want to assess if the difference between them is statistically significant. For now, I am using a Welch t-test (which only requires the knowledge of the mean, the standard deviation and the number of points in my two populations). And I get results, no problem, I use the p value to know if the difference is significant or not.

My question is that by doing so, I ignore the uncertainties associated to each point of these populations. I know these uncertainties, it is [2 ppb + 2%] (ppb is the unit of pollutant concentrations in the atmosphere). How should I proceed to include these uncertainties in my Welch t-test calculations?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Hervé

PS: I am using R